# Formatting fields with in a Lookup in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following lookup:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Claim_Id.Value, Fields!Claim_Id.Value, Fields!Claim_Diary_Due_Date.Value, "DiaryDataset")
```

and the date field currently shows as `MM/dd/yyyy` and I'd like it to be `yyyy-MM-dd`. I tried to use the text box properties and some various formatting expression things (like `format()` and `Cstr()`) to change it and nothing so far has worked.

Is there a way to format a field within a lookup?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your lookup in a CDATE function.

```
=CDATE(Lookup(Fields!Claim_Id.Value, Fields!Claim_Id.Value, Fields!Claim_Diary_Due_Date.Value, "DiaryDataset"))
```

It will convert the string value to a date which can then be formatted with the FORMAT property of the Text Box.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017):

> The CDate function converts the value to a date.

Comment: How is your answer related to the problem?